# HTML Multiple Select form not working

Tags: php

I am new in PHP.
Please check the following code; multiple select is not working. Not sure why. Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="test.php">
    <select  name="fin[]" multiple ="multiple" class = "multiple_select" id = "selected_options_fin" style="height: 200px">
        <option value="week_period">Week Period</option>
        <option value="comments_approved">Comments Approved</option>
        <option value="comment_replies">Comment Replies</option>
        <option value="avarage_response_time">Average Response Time</option>
        <option value="avarage_response_time_in_minutes">Average Response Time in Minutes</option>
        <option value="commenter_visits">Commenter Visits</option>
        <option value="percentage_of_new_visits">% New Visits</option>
        <option value="number_of_goal_completions"># of Goal Completions</option>
        <option value="conversions_rate">Conversions Rate</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name = "submit1" Value = "SUBMIT" id="submit_fin">                
</form>          


<?php

if (isset($_POST['fin'])) {
    $fin_array = $_POST['fin'];
    $loop_count = 0;
    foreach ($fin_array as $key => $value) {
        $loop_count++;
        echo 'Column $loop_count || Array Key = $key || Value = $value<br />';
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What actually you are getting?

Comment: Shows exactly the same page as it was before submitting form @ABCatella

Comment: Default form action is `GET` To use post - set `action="post"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering
First line need to have

form action="test.php" method="post"